# How to disable the execution info (execution timestamp, elapsed time, user etc.) in Google Colab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

After I execute some code cell in Google Colab, there is a piece of information saved and displayed when hovering over the execute icon, which shows the execution time, time elapsed, the user who executed it, etc. When I look at the .ipynb source code this is stored as JSON as thus (prettified):

```
"metadata": {
  ...
  "executionInfo": {
    "status": "ok",
    "timestamp": <execution time>,
    "user_tz": ...,
    "elapsed": <elapsed time>,
    "user": {
      "displayName": <Google account name>,
      "photoUrl": ...,
      "userId": ...
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

I don't want to omit cell output, but can I somehow disable this feature? It is kind of annoying that it actually displays when and who executed this. I know I can delete this information locally, but this has to be done every time it's modified by Colab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to suppress this information other than the mechanisms you mention: 1) enabling private outputs, which prevents saving any outputs. Or, 2) editing the notebook by hand.